# Aumentar la fuente de las etiquetas de datos ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

tengo unos dendrogramas y requiero que las categorias (eje x) salgan en un tamaño más grande. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
dendroend01 <- ggplot(ggd01) + 
               labs(x = "Students", y = "Distance", ylim(0,NA), 
                    title = "Dendrograma") 
               theme_classic() + 
               geom_hline(yintercept = 0.45, colour = "darkred", 
                          linetype="dashed", 
                          size=1)

dendroend01 <- dendroend01 + 
               theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),  
                     axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
                     axis.line.x = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a utilizar:

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = %valor%))
```

donde el `%valor%` es el número que defina el tamaño de la letra. Quizás no sea `axis.text.x` y tengas que probar otras opciones. No obstante, el resto debería valer.